# Google Maps API V3 Markers Not Showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have used Version 2 for quite some time and decided it was time to go to Version 3 as part of a major site update. I based all my code on "[Mike Williams' tutorial The Basics - Part 3: Loading the data from an XML file translated to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html)". After hours of fine-tuning I had it all working, including clustering and custom markers.

I was a very happy bunny and keen to show it off. Then to my disappointment I discovered that it didn't work in either IE or Firefox (I had been testing it in Chrome).

I'm well aware that Google Maps API is not an easy thing to work with, but is there any reason why I should get this behaviour with different browsers? The map can be seen by going to [www.littlehotels.co.uk/new/](http://www.littlehotels.co.uk/new/) and clicking on "Map Search". The code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Little Hotels of Spain - Google Map</title>
<meta name="description" content="Little Hotels provides maps showing the location of hotels, using Google Maps to create both a street/road map and a satellite image.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Little Hotels, Little Hotels of Spain, Spain, mainland spain, balearic, balearics, canary, canaries, small, hotel, hotels, map, google map, holiday, holidays">
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333333;}
a:link, a:visited, a:hover {color: #FF6600; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;}
h1{font-size: 16px; color: #2B8CB9; font-weight: bold;}
#content{padding: 0 5px 0; width: 640px;}
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
.verdana{font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9px; color: #666666;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
      var gmarkers = []; 

     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;
      var markerclusterer = null;

  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/hotel_icon.png',
      new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));
  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/hotel_shadow.png',
      new google.maps.Size(51, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: image,
        shadow: shadow
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function initialize() {
      var lat = 0;
      var lng = 0;
      var zoomzoom = 0;
      var query = location.search.substring(1);
      var pairs = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();
        if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "zoom") {zoomzoom = parseInt(value);}
      }
 var thisLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var myOptions = {
center: thisLatlng,
zoom: zoomzoom,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   streetViewControl: false,
   zoomControl: true,
   zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
   }
   }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

      downloadUrl("php-to-xml.php", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var html=markers[i].getAttribute("html");
          var hotel=markers[i].getAttribute("hotel");

          var marker = createMarker(point,hotel,html);
        }

var clusterStyles = [
  {
    opt_textColor: '#5a7aba',
    url: '../images/cluster_icon.png',
    height: 40,
    width: 40
  }
];
        var mcOptions = {gridSize: 35, maxZoom: 8, styles: clusterStyles};
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers,mcOptions);
      });
    }

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(300,50)
  });

//]]>
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="content">
<h1>Little Hotels Map Search</h1>
<span class="verdana">Click on the icons for more information or use the Google controls to zoom, scroll, pan and change view.<br /><br /></span>
<table border=1 bordercolor="#666666">
      <tr>
        <td>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 450px"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<br />
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks for any advice anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1):

The returned XML is not well-formed. It contains :

```
pretty "pueblos blancos"
```

you have to use `&quot;` for the double-quotes or a CDATA-section.

Because of that you'll not be able to parse the returned data as XML

Comment: I was homing in on the same sort of thing. I found a few examples of ñ in there that were stopping it. I hadn't tracked down the " until I read your post though. Thanks. I've deleted the " and changed ñ to n just to get it working. Now I just have to work out how to convert them within my php-to-xml file so that it becomes a permanent and clean solution.

Thanks for taking the time and trouble to help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the PHP-skript

Answer (score 1):

I get the error in Firefox:

Error: not well-formed
Source File: http://www.littlehotels.co.uk/new/maps/php-to-xml.php
Line: 1, Column: 1722

Check with an XML validator.

Answer (score 0):

Dr Molle, this is the PHP script:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
header('charset:UTF-8');

require_once('../Connections/MySQL_extranet.php'); 

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("ñ",'&ntilde;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

mysql_select_db($database_MySQL_extranet, $MySQL_extranet);
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT hid, hotel, lat, lng, picture, summary FROM ex_hotel WHERE country = 'spain'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"; 

echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo ' html="&lt;img src=&quot;../images/' . $row['picture'] . '&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; height=&quot;108&quot; width=&quot;155&quot; style=&quot;margin-right:8px;&quot;&gt; &lt;div style=&quot;width:320px&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;' . 'http://www.littlehotels.co.uk/new/spain/' . $row['hid'] . '.php&quot; target=&quot;_parent&quot; &gt;' . parseToXML($row['hotel']) . '&lt;/a&gt; &lt;br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;verdana&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;'.parseToXML($row['summary']).'&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"';
  echo ' lat="' . $row['lat'] . '"';
  echo ' lng="' . $row['lng'] . '"';
  echo ' />';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

The parsetoXML function is supposed to solve my original problem. It works on quotes but not on the ñ character. I have variously tried replacing ñ with ñ &0141; and n. None of them work. However, I've just settled for avoiding use of ñ at the moment. I'll come back to address this problem again when I have more time.

Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

've just been looking into the same issue.  It seems the custom icon shadow feature is being dropped anyway.

"All shadows have been removed in the visual refresh. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefreshChanges